Fourier Transform (train of impulses)
Perhaps this question has occurred somewhere before, but I learn more if I ask the question myself. We have to determine the Fourier transform of the following function: $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{10} \frac{1}{3^n} \delta(t-5n)$, but I am not sure how to go about this because I am not so sure what I have in front of me. I also cannot find a question similar to this one with a detailed explanation. To some extent, I understand that it is just a discrete function, and that for every value of $n$, there arises a peak everytime $t=5n$, with the corresponding "amplitude" $a$ but the problem occurs up when I need to actually transform it.
First, the general form of a similar function is given as $f(t) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty s[n] \delta(t-n)$, which then gives that the discrete-time Fourier transform is given by $\mathcal{F}\{f(t)\}(\omega) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} s[n] e^{-i \omega n}$. In this case $s[n]=3^{-n}$, I guess? But then I still can't really imagine, in either case, what that delta function actually does with the entire transformation and to the summation. And then how I should work with that, in general.
A hint is given that we can make use of the fact that $ \sum_{n=0}^N a r^{-n} = a \frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}$, but even then I get confused because the delta function also depends on $n$ right? so $a$ is also dependend of $n$ right?

My brain is even more fogged after writing this

So, after much thought, I may have an idea. Since the peak of $f(t)$, only occurs when $t=5n$, I would say the the period is equal to 5. Which makes $s[n] = 3^{-5n}$ instead of $s[n] = 3^{-n}$. Is this true?

You can use the fact that the Fourier transform of $\delta(t-t_{0})$ is given by $e^{-i\omega t_{0}}$ and that it's a linear integral transformation, hence your sum of deltas will be the sum of Fourier transform of each delta.
Putting these together you get
$$\mathcal{F}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{10}3^{-n}\delta(t-5n)\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{10}3^{-n}\mathcal{F}(\delta(t-5n)) = \sum_{n=0}^{10}3^{-n}e^{-i5n\omega} = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{3e^{i5\omega}}\right)^{11}-1}{\frac{1}{3e^{i5\omega}}-1}.$$

This is a very simple explanation, but an observation that is very helpful. Didn't know it's a linear integral transformation. Thanks!

I don't know what's troubling you exactly. I'm guessing this is what you'd do, if not tell me since I'm yet to study the Fourier Transform:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathscr F_t\{f(t)\}(\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^{10}\frac{1}{3^n}\delta(t-5n)e^{-i\omega t}\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{10}\frac{1}{3^n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(t-5n)e^{- i\omega t}\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{10}\frac{e^{-5 i\omega n}}{3^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{10}\left(\frac{e^{-5 i\omega}}{3}\right)^n\\
&=\dfrac{1-\left(\dfrac{e^{-5 i\omega}}{3}\right)^{11}}{1-\dfrac{e^{-5 i\omega}}{3}}=\dfrac{3^{11}-e^{-55 i\omega}}{3^{10}(1-e^{-5 i\omega})}
\end{aligned}
$$

Sorry for the lack of clarity, I got stuck mainly in transforming the discrete function. I knew somewhat what the function represented, but not how to deal with the integral and summation. The previous answer noted that it is a linear transformation. Thanks also for the explanation!

Yes, integrals are linear operators and in this case we were able to interchange summation with integration because the summation is finite.

Thanks! By the way, I think you mean $e^{-2 \pi i f t}$? Because $\omega = 2\pi f$

And if the integral were not finite, what would change? My simple brain would say that that summation still does not depend on $t$, so can be seen as "constant".
